# User Control in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding, user-controls

I'm trying to revisit this as I can't seem to find an answer. I have created a User Control which works awfully well when I hard code in the Parent_ID. However, I'd like to have the Parent_ID assigned dynamically according to a value from a GridView's row.

Here is the User Control's CodeBehind:

```
Public Class Comments
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Public _name As String
<System.ComponentModel.Bindable(True), System.ComponentModel.Browsable(True)> _
Public Property Parent_ID() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Parent_ID Is Nothing Then Parent_ID = "-1"

        DataSource_Comments.FilterParameters(0).DefaultValue = Parent_ID
        'lbl_Parent_Alert.Text = "Parent_ID: " & Parent_ID
    End If
End Sub   
End Class
```

ASP.net aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
        CodeBehind="About.aspx.vb" Inherits="MOO.About" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Comments_Control"  Src="~/Comments.ascx" %>

    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource_Missed_Yesterday" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainMOOConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM func_Missed_Yesterday() Order By Total_Price DESC"
            >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GV_Missed_Yesterday" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataSource_Missed_Yesterday" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid_View">
           <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="num_Order_Num" HeaderText="Order Number"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="mem_Order_Notes" HeaderText="Order Notes"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Notes">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID ='lbl' runat="server" text='<%#Eval("num_Order_Num") %>'/>
                        <uc:Comments_Control id="Comments_Control_ID" runat="server" Parent_ID='<%#Eval("num_Order_Num") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </asp:Content>
```

Aspx.vb page:

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class About
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
Sub GV_Missed_Yesterday_DataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV_Missed_Yesterday.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Again, if I hard code this line:

```
<uc:Comments_Control id="Comments_Control_ID" runat="server" Parent_ID='<%#Eval("num_Order_Num") %>' />
```

As:

```
<uc:Comments_Control id="Comments_Control_ID" runat="server" Parent_ID='1162519' />
```

I see the appropriate comments for Order 1162519. When I leave it as Eval("num_Order_Num"), I get nothing.

I thank you in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I believe that the controls in a template are first created (at which time your `Page_Load` event handler would run in the user control) and then any binding language expressions are evaluated.  So by testing the value of `Parent_ID` in the user control's `Page_Load` routine, you're catching it too early.

Try using the `PreRender` event instead of the `Load` event to test `Parent_ID` for a value.  That will execute right before rendering, well after any binding expressions have been evaluated.

Comment: I just changed:  Me.Load to Me.PreRender in my User Control's Code Behind and IT WORKS!!!! Thanks, @Ann L.!

Answer (score 1):

Yeap... Ann L. was correct. The controls in a template are created first than the binding event.

You could also use the GV_Missed_Yesterday_DataBound method, if you couldn't use the PreRender. Some cases, you must do the operations before the prerender.
So you could set the Parent_ID for the control at the DataBound method and also create a method in the Comments_Control that executes the code :

```
DataSource_Comments.FilterParameters(0).DefaultValue = Parent_ID
```

For the same problems most of times there is a lot of possible solutions.

I've written this new solution in order to satisfy anyone who face the same problem but can't use the PreRender event.

Comment: "For the same problems most of times there is a lot of possible solutions."  Quite right!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a Page.DataBind() on the page load of your User Control.

Comment: This answer is pretty short on content. Care to provide some more detail, ideally with a code snippet?

Comment: @chris the user control is created before the databinding, in order to get the values on the user control instance, page data binding has to be invoked manually.  However looking through the code the user provided he should just do the eval code on the actual user control not the reference of a user control in the template. It really depends on what you want to accomplish further because forcing the binding might cause issues for you later

Comment: Instead of putting all of that into a comment, please edit your answer to include it.